# noob div tag issue - auto resize and positioning

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a website for myself for most of the day learning about and getting a reactive navigation bar to work but now I want to add more content I seem to have missed something. The nav menus all work fine when it is resized and I have checked it on my mobile. my issue now is the next div I add does not appear under the nav bar but behind it like the nav bar div (header) has a 0 height value.

The website is live so I could check it on my mobile. cscustomsbikes.co.uk

I'm fairly certain it is a simple fix for someone experienced but i'm struggling.

I have tried setting the header div height to auto but that didn't work. I can add a fixed height in and that works fine but when the page is shrunken down to mobile size the pop out menu expands over the pageinfo div instead of pushing it down... because its fixed.

the source code:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#menu').slicknav();
});
```

```css
    @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    
    .body {
     max-width: 1200px;
     height: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     padding-left: 10px;
     padding-right: 10px;
     }
    
    .header{
     height:inherit;
    }
     
    .logo {
     float:left;
     width: 200px;
     height:auto;
     display: block;
     }
     
    .Navlinks{
      font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu 
    Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
      font-size: 18px;
      font-style: normal;
      text-decoration: underline;
      color:#B0AAAA;
    }
    
    ul.menu{
     margin:0;
     padding-top:0px;
    }
    
    .pageinfo {
     border-color: #000000;
     border-top:3px;
     border-bottom: 3px;
     font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", "sans-serif";
     background-color: #FB070B
    }
    
    
    
     /*Global view*/
    @media(min-width:769px){
    
    
    ul.menu{
     padding-top:20px;
    }
    
    ul.menu li{
     height:auto;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    padding-left:20px;
    }
    
     .slicknav_menu{
      display:none;
     }
     
    }
    
     /*Tablet View*/
    @media (max-width: 768px){
     
     
    .logo {
      width: 170px;
     }
     
    ul.menu{
      float: right;
      list-style-type:none; 
     }
    
    ul.menu li{
      margin-bottom: 5px;
     }
     
    .Navlinks {
     font-size: 14px;
     }
     
    .slicknav_menu{
      display:none;
     }
     
    }
    
    
     /*Mobile View*/
    @media (max-width: 400px){
      
    .header {
      height:auto;
      float: left;
     }
     
    .logo {
      width: 100px;
     float:left;
     }
     
    #menu{
      display: none;
     }
     
    .slicknav_menu{
     height: auto;
     display:block;
     float: right;
     }
     
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SlickNav/1.0.10/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>

<div id="pagebody" class="body"> </div>

<div id="header" class="header"> 
  <img src="Resources/Logos/Logo.gif" alt="C.S.Customs logo" class="logo" id="logo">
  <ul class="menu" id="menu">
    <li>
      <a class="Navlinks" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="Navlinks" href="contact.html">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="Navlinks" href="contact.html">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="Navlinks" href="contact.html">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="Navlinks" href="contact.html">Home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="pageinfo" class="pageinfo">Main editable region</div>
```

This will ultimately become my template for the site and the pageinfo will be the editable region.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle containing your code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you float an element (it’s the `li`s for you), that element’s parent div (`ul.menu`) will not be concerned about its position and stop expanding its size to encompass the floated child. The solution you’re looking for is called a *clearfix*. Refer to this SO question: [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/what-methods-of-clearfix-can-i-use) for implementation.

For more information on floating elements and their implications, you can, for instance, refer to [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/), especially the section “The Great Collapse”.

Comment: Thank you. Clear answer and some tutorage to boot, couldn’t have asked for better 

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `li`s have `float: right`.

You need to clear before proceeding otherwise they'll float over the content.

Try adding `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` just before closing the header's `</div>`.

Comment: Thank you. This has helped me a lot.